# NIM game not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie in programming with python, but managed to program small NIM game. The game is human vs computer where each player removes a number of straws(from 1 to 3). I have a problem is that when playing for some reason, computer doesn't remove any straws, after his turn the number of straws are still the same, also after all straws are removed, it doesn't show congratulations message and message to play again.. A help would be very appreciated..

```
player1=raw_input("Enter your name. ")
player2="Computer"
howMany=0
gameover=False
strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)

if (strawsNumber%4)==1:
    strawsNumber+=1

def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    while removedNumber>strawsNumber:
         removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
         strawsNumber-=removedNumber
    return strawsNumber

def removingStrawsHuman():
    global strawsNumber
    strawsNumber-=howMany
    return strawsNumber

def humanLegalMove():
    global howMany
    legalMove=False
    while not legalMove:
        print("It's your turn, ",player1)
        howMany=int(input("How many straws do you want to remove?(from 1 to 3) "))
        if  howMany>3 or howMany<1:
            print("Enter a number between 1 and 3.")
        else:
            legalMove=True
    while howMany>strawsNumber:
        print("The entered number is greater than a number of straws remained.")
        howMany=int(input("How many straws do you want to remove?"))
    return howMany

def checkWinner(player):
    if strawsNumber==0:
        print(player," wins.")
        global gameover
        gameover=True
        return gameover

def resetGameover():
    global gameover
    gameover=False
    return gameover

def game():
    global strawsNumber
    strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)
    while gameover==False:
        print("It's ",player2,"turn. The number of straws left: ",removingStrawsComputer())
        checkWinner(player1)
        if gameover==True:
            break
        humanLegalMove()        
        print("The number of straws left: ",removingStrawsHuman())
        checkWinner(player2)


def playAgain():
    answer=input("Do you want to play again?(y/n)")
    resetGameover()
    while answer=="y":
        game()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing the game")

game()
playAgain()
```

Comment: What's more important than writing a program is to know how to debug a bad one! :) Add some `print` commands to trace how the control is passing between the functions. You will easily be able to figure out where it is going wrong! Good Luck!

Comment: You should ask your question on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gerrat non-working code is off-topic on code review.

Comment: Ha.  Sorry, my bad.  ...was sort of hoping there was another stack-related site that handled this *type* of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to fix your indentation

```
def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    while removedNumber>strawsNumber:
         removedNumber=random.randint(1,3) 
         strawsNumber-=removedNumber
    return strawsNumber
```

will only remove the straws from the strawNumber `if removedNumber > strawsNumber`

to fix it correct your indentation

```
def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    while removedNumber>strawsNumber:
         removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    strawsNumber-=removedNumber #now always remove the straws
    return strawsNumber
```

Comment: Thank you very much! really appreciate your help. Could you please help how to make this player vs player game? I know what I should put same method removingStrawsHuman, but can't get all checking correctly..